# Differences shallow and deep CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network

I try to confirm the performance differences between shallow CNN model (AlexNet) and deep CNN model(ResNet). When the training datasets are small, shallow CNN outperforms the deep CNN. But when the training datasets became to large, the performance differences decrease. Finally, deep CNN outperforms shallow CNN. Could you please these detailed backgrounds or let me know the related paper? Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since this hasn't been answered in a while, I'll give my humble understanding of shallow vs deep CNNs based on multiple experimentations using different models/datasets. The main points are summarized below:

[image]